# Translation of a painting's signature, ink + gold (Characters identified: 日本製略曆)

Tags: culture, history

I am very grateful for helping me with signature on lovely Chinese painting, I have one more in my collection, judging by the back of it it has at least 100 years. It is painted with ink and gold, the signature is next to it but again, I would be very grateful if you could help me with the translation of signature.
Once again thank you!!!!
pictures below
[image]

Comment: 日本製 (Japan made) 略(brief/ rough) 曆 (Calendar)

Comment: :) thank you, it only shows how little I know, Tang Ho, you are a great adviser, I couldn't thank you enough! all the best

Answer (score 1):

The characters are:

> 日本製 (Japan made) 略(brief/ rough) 曆 (Calendar)

I am not quite sure what '略曆' (brief Calendar) means. I have never heard of this term. My guess is, it is an old term (may be Japanese only) for '月曆' (monthly calendar) which is brief in details, unlike '日曆' (daily calendar) which list much more detailed information about each day on the Calendar

This painting might be the original art work for reproduction on a calendar

Comment: 略歷(shinjitai: 略歴) I searched Internet but only find this. It's a Janpanese word and means "brief personal record". I think that's a handwritting mistake.

Comment: 略歴 is certainly Japanese and it could refer to something like a brief resumé or CV.